# What is the time complexity of the following nested loops?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, big-o, time-complexity

```
for i=1 to n
    for j=1 to i
        for k=1 to j
            x+=1
```

I believe this to be O(n<sup>3</sup>)

```
for i=1 to n
    for j=1 to i
        for k=1 to i
            x+=1
```

I also think this one is n<sup>3</sup> because the innermost loop is still dependent on the outermost loop.

Please verify my answer and explain why I am wrong.

Comment: It is illustrative to graph n vs the runtime of your algorithm for various values of n (but include a fixed duration sleep/pause at the x+=1 step so that you can work with reasonable values of n).  Look at the shape of the graph to get an initial idea of the complexity.

Comment: Or just plot the value of x, because it can only go up by one.  But yes, sum(1..n) is n*(n+1)/2, which is in the O(n^2) complexity class, like n*n.  So loop boundaries that depend linearly on the outer-loop loop counter don't change things.

Comment: In practice it's usually a lot faster, and can be really significant if there's an early-out that usually happens.  (e.g. consider looking for a duplicate char in a string, checking the whole string for a repeat of the current char, vs. checking just the previous elements.  On a giant string with no repeats of the very first char, it's huge.)  Early outs complicate the complexity analysis, because you have to either consider that case separately, or account for how often the early out will be taken.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the first one correct. Then you can easily argue that the complexity of the second version is at least that of the first version. Why? The only difference between versions is that the second has `k = 1 to i` and the first has `k = 1 to j`. But in the first version, `j` is always less than or equal to `i`. So in the second version, the loop with `k` will always run more often.

Consider this bit of code now:

```
for i=1 to n
    for j=1 to n
        for k=1 to n
            x+=1
```

First, show that the time complexity of this is **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**. Then, make an argument similar to the one I make above to show that the complexity of this code is greater than or equal to that of your second version. Conclude that the complexity of all three code segments must be **O(n<sup>3</sup>)** if the complexity of the first one is, and then show the complexity of the first is **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**.